# How can I choose algorithms in a function

Tags: algorithm, julia

the scenario likes this:

There is an algorithm called **alg1**, and another algorithm called **alg2**.

And there is an entry function called `solve`, how can I pass **alg1** to **solve** then I can use **alg1** to compute, and pass **alg2** to compute with **alg2**?

```
solve(a, b, alg1) #return the results computed with alg1
solve(a, b, alg2) #return the results computed with alg2
```

Do I need to write the algorithms as functions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A typical elegant API could be based on the multiple dispatch mechanism and could look like this:

```
abstract type AbstractAlgo end
struct Algo1 <: AbstractAlgo end
struct Algo2 <: AbstractAlgo
    param::Int
end

function solve(a,b,alg::T) where T<:AbstractAlgo 
    throw("Algorithm $T is not yet implemented")
end
function solve(a,b,alg::Algo1) 
   println("solving...")
end
```

Some tests:

```
julia> solve(1,2,Algo1())
solving...

julia> solve(1,2,Algo2(777))
ERROR: "Algorithm Algo2 is not yet implemented"
```

Answer (score 3):

In julia you can pass funcions as parameters, so:

```
function alg1(a,b)
...
end

solve(a,b,alg) = alg(a,b)

# calling solve
answer = solve(a,b,alg1)
```

Of course there are other ways, as transforming algs is structures and employing multiple dispatch, but the solution above should answer the question..